# Using move semantics with std::vectors under g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, fedora

I'm attempting to get a program written on my home copy of VS2010 to compile on the university's version of Fedora (`Linux version 3.1.9-1.fc16.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-15.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1) (GCC) )` ).
The program uses various c++11 features such as auto types and move constructors.
This all works no trouble in VS2010, but when I compile it in linux (`g++ -g -Wall -std=c++0x -pedantic`), I get the following slew of errors:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/vector:63:0,
                 from src/OpenGL/Renderer.h:4,
                 from src/Wolfenstein3D2011.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In function ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Wulf::MapWall, _Args = {const Wulf::MapWall&}]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   instantiated from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapWall*, std::vector<Wulf::MapWall> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapWall*, bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapWall*, std::vector<Wulf::MapWall> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapWall*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:259:63:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapWall*, std::vector<Wulf::MapWall> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapWall*, _Tp = Wulf::MapWall]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:280:9:   instantiated from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Wulf::MapWall, _Alloc = std::allocator<Wulf::MapWall>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<Wulf::MapWall>]’
src/Map/Map.h:17:8:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Wulf::MapWall::MapWall(const Wulf::MapWall&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7: note: candidates are:
src/Map/MapWall.h:18:3: note: Wulf::MapWall::MapWall(Wulf::MapWall&&)
src/Map/MapWall.h:18:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Wulf::MapWall’ to ‘Wulf::MapWall&&’
src/Map/MapWall.h:12:3: note: Wulf::MapWall::MapWall(Wulf::Direction)
src/Map/MapWall.h:12:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Wulf::MapWall’ to ‘Wulf::Direction’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h: In function ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Wulf::MapNode, _Args = {const Wulf::MapNode&}]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   instantiated from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapNode*, std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapNode*, bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapNode*, std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapNode*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:259:63:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Wulf::MapNode*, std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> >, _ForwardIterator = Wulf::MapNode*, _Tp = Wulf::MapNode]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:280:9:   instantiated from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = Wulf::MapNode, _Alloc = std::allocator<Wulf::MapNode>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7:   instantiated from ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>, _Args = {const std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>&}]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:77:3:   instantiated from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*, std::vector<std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> > >, _ForwardIterator = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*, bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:119:41:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*, std::vector<std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> > >, _ForwardIterator = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:259:63:   instantiated from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*, std::vector<std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> > >, _ForwardIterator = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>*, _Tp = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:280:9:   instantiated from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::vector<Wulf::MapNode>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> = std::vector<std::vector<Wulf::MapNode> >]’
src/Map/Map.h:17:8:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Wulf::MapNode::MapNode(const Wulf::MapNode&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_construct.h:76:7: note: candidates are:
src/Map/MapNode.h:15:3: note: Wulf::MapNode::MapNode(Wulf::MapNode&&)
src/Map/MapNode.h:15:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Wulf::MapNode’ to ‘Wulf::MapNode&&’
src/Map/MapNode.h:10:3: note: Wulf::MapNode::MapNode(Wulf::coord, Wulf::coord, Wulf::word, Wulf::word)
src/Map/MapNode.h:10:3: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1
```

Since Map/Map.h:17 is `class Map {`, I've got no idea what's causing this.
The only lines I can imagine as causing this are in Map/Map.cpp and are
`nodes[x].push_back(MapNode(x - halfwidth, y - halfheight, map[i], objs[i]));`
and
`walls.push_back(MapWall(air ? DIRECTION_WEST : DIRECTION_EAST));`
Both of these work fine under VS2010, successfully moving the temporary into the vector, but obviously not under g++.
Is this some quirk of the compiler, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: "There are no rules in crystal ball fights." - "No, there *is* one rule: Bring a crystal ball."

Comment: This can't be caused by the lines you posted (`walls.push_back...`). The compiler is telling you it failed to copy a vector of vectors of `MapNodes`. Find it somewhere in the code. MAYBE you need `Map::Map(const Map&)` for something, and it has such member...

Comment: If you post some (minimal?) code reproducing it's more likely you get a good answer. Could you post MapNode and MapWall ?
Do you have your own move constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the error messages, you are trying to copy a `Map`, which contains a `vector<MapWall>`, and this is failing because `MapWall` is not copyable.

If these types are supposed to be copyable, then you need to add a copy constructor to `MapWall`; your user-declared move constructor means that one won't be implicitly generated. (I might hazard a guess that VS2010 is incorrectly generating one; that would explain why your code works there).

Otherwise, you might find it easier to track the rogue copy operation by adding a private, deleted copy constructor to `Map` - then you should get an error message showing you exactly what's trying to copy it.

Comment: That honestly hadn't occurred to me, since `Map` doesn't have a copy constructor, but you were right. One of the functions was passing a `Map` by value instead of reference.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing those messages, I am sure it's your fault, and VS2010 being too permisive

This :

```
src/Map/MapNode.h:15:3: note: Wulf::MapNode::MapNode(Wulf::MapNode&&)
src/Map/MapNode.h:15:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Wulf::MapNode’ to ‘Wulf::MapNode&&’
src/Map/MapNode.h:10:3: note: Wulf::MapNode::MapNode(Wulf::coord, Wulf::coord, Wulf::word, Wulf::word)
```

means that you tried to pass lreference object to a move constructor, or the real constructor.

The same error is next :

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Wulf::MapWall’ to ‘Wulf::MapWall&&’
```

Without seeing some code, it's not possible to tell what exactly you did.